# STM32 External Interrupt via GPIO cannot be triggered after waking up from STOP mode

Tags: stm32, firmware, sleep, stm32l

I have a problem with a project based on an STM32L051. I want to use the stop mode and wake up on an external (GPIO based) IRQ. This all works great but after the MCU woke up once, no IRQs seem to work. I have a very simple IRQ handler which just outputs some debug info for now. Naturally I do hal-initialize again after I woke up. **Also the whole thing works when I use stand-by mode instead of stop mode**. I tried to enable the related IRQ via `HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);` explicitly but it did not help. Any idea what could be missing?

Comment: Is the GPIO clock still running in stop mode?

Comment: I don't know but as the the wake-up works, I guess yes.

Answer (score 1):

For me, a simple `HAL_NVIC_SystemReset();` did the trick.

**Update:**

I also found out that this is sufficient and does not require a reset:

```
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(IRQn, 1, 1);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(IRQn);
```